# Convert timestamp in seconds to a timestamp with current date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column called timeElapsed in seconds.
I take input from user to get a specific timestamp.
I want to add this specific timestamp with the timeElapsed column value.

For example:

```
user enters: 2021-07-08 10:00:00.0000
First entry in timeElapsed column is 80.1234.
New Column should be 2021-07-08 10:01:20.1234
```

so far, this is my code

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'userData': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                   'timeElapsed': [0, 1.6427, 2.5185,5.3293,6.6699,37.4221,67.4378]})

takeDateInput = str(datetime.strptime(input("Enter current timestamp: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MS"),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

def myfunc2(x):
   time.gmtime(x) 

print(df1['timeElapsed'].apply(myfunc2))
```

I am trying to convert the seconds value to get a formatted hh:mm:ss timestamp using the myfun2. But I am not able to convert it. Is this the current approach?

Any direction as to how to achieve my final goal, would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeElapsed` value you're trying to add is best represented with a `Timedelta`. Keep the inputted timestamp as `Datetime` object (not a string), then you can just add the seconds as `Timedelta`:

```
takeDateInput = datetime.strptime(input("Enter current timestamp: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MS"),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

def myfunc2(x):
   return takeDateInput + pd.Timedelta(x, unit='sec')

print(df1['timeElapsed'].apply(myfunc2))
```

Comment: One observation. The milliseconds value gets rounded up and gets added to seconds value. For example: 61.6543s becomes 00:01:02 instead of 00:01:01.6543. Is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: See the [Timedelta docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), you might want to try `unit='micro'`.